# Get a dropdown for Views: Filter: Taxonomy Term Name

Tags: 7, views

I'm using taxonomy term name to filter views based on their taxonomy. I've tried basic or Better Exposed Filters and setting a relationship but still no option for a drop-down select menu.

I can't use filter by "Taxonomy Term: Term" because this uses the TID not Term Name in URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your views is based in content type, you should use the term reference field in the filter. Example:

I have a content type of services composed of *title, body, service category(term reference)*.
In my services views, I will add service category as filter. In my **Better Exposed Filter**, I can configure that service category if I want a drop down filter or autocomplete.

Using taxonomy term name shows autocomplete filter.

I hope it helps